# Display image on top of blurred background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display an image on top of that same image, but blurred and as background.

```css
.background-image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/366968/pexels-photo-366968.jpeg?w=1153&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  height: 800px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/366968/pexels-photo-366968.jpeg?w=1153&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="hero-image"></div>
```

The present code doesn't show the hero image.

Tried creating div inside another div but failed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, why you want to `position:fixed` your `background1` but, using this below shown approach you can do.

But if you try to nest your `background2` inside `background1` div, then the `blur` filter will get applied to both the images and i think, you don't want that.

**Points:**

- whenever using `background-image` you need to define `height` and `width` otherwise it won't be visible on `browser`.
- when using `position: absolute` try having a `relative` parent `div` as well, helps you control your layout.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  /* */
}

.background-image {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-6.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-208-204-2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="background-image">
  </div>
  <div class="hero-image"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like charm. I want both background-image and hero-image position:fixed. But how to I avoid scroll bar on the right?

Comment: you have given a `height:800px` this may be the reason of scrolls. You can give `overflow:hidden;` to the `parent div` or `body` tag. No scrollbars then

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to position the hero image [`fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) as well. This way, you can stack it on top of the background image. The order is ensured using a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

In the below, I have edited your styles to make the order consistent and show the most important pieces first: how is an element positioned, where, at what size, then the background, then other stuff. You can now see the overlap and differences between the two images easily.

Note that the `-webkit-` prefixed version of the `filter` is [not needed](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

```css
.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 750px;
  
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/366968/pexels-photo-366968.jpeg?w=1153&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  background-size: cover;
  
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.hero-image {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 750px;

  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/366968/pexels-photo-366968.jpeg?w=1153&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="hero-image"></div>
```